# Opening Chrome browser on a variable page using vbscript

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

This is my code for opening Chrome browser on a variable page using vbscript:

```
Set browobj = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

siteA = "http://...../"
browobj.Run "chrome -url " & siteA

WScript.Sleep OneSecond*60
siteB = "http://..../Gest.do?operation=export&eser=123&ver=456"  
browobj.Run "chrome -url " & siteB  

Set browobj = Nothing
```

The first step opens the web page ( *siteA* ) for user authentication:

```
siteA = "http://...../"
browobj.Run "chrome -url " & siteA
```

The second step opens a link ( *siteB* ) where you pass variables for downloading an excel file :

```
WScript.Sleep OneSecond*60
siteB = "http://..../Gest.do?operation=export&eser=123&ver=456"  
browobj.Run "chrome -url " & siteB
```

The second link ( *siteB* ) with the variables is opened in a new Chrome tab and the download is stopped.

Instead if the second link ( *siteB* )  opens in the same tab of the *siteA* the download is started. Tried manually.

**I need reuse the same tab on is opening the *siteA*.**

How to do opening the second link ( *siteB* )  opens in the same tab of the *siteA* ?

Please can you help me ?

**Edit #01**

```
browobj.Run start & siteB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since chrome is available as a command:

```
chrome /new-tab somesite.com
```

However if `chrome` isnt available as a command but IS the default browser you can use:

```
start "" "https://somesite.com"
```

This should make it open in a new tab on the active window.

If you can't guarantee Chrome is the default browser. You can find the path to the chrome.exe and use something like:

```
"<Path of chrome here>" /new-tab "https://somesite.com"
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried your suggestion without success. Please see **Edit #01** in my first question. Chrome is the default browser.

Comment: @Golia try `browobj.Run "chrome /new-tab -url " & siteB `

Comment: Okay, the siteB is opened in new tab and not in the existing tab ( siteA) on Chrome.
I need reuse the same tab on is opening the siteA.

Comment: Is there a particular reason? I don't believe its possible.

Comment: The second link ( siteB ) with the variables is opened in a new Chrome tab and the download is stopped. But has worked with `browobj.Run "chrome /-tab -url " & siteB`
Thanks!